# dos imágenes diferentes con la misma ruta pero cambian para el signo de interrogación (?) html

Tags: html5

Tenía una pregunta sobre cómo YouTube hace esto

`<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lWQ69WX7-hA/hqdefault.jpg">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lWQ69WX7-hA/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEZCPYBEIoBSFXyq4qpAwsIARUAAIhCGAFwAQ==&rs=AOn4CLBvpzVsrJbZSguks3HsuhS1fWzr8A">`

muestra de un vistazo que la ruta es idéntica, pero a la segunda imagen le sigue un signo de interrogación (?) y se ve que la imagen cambia (en tamaño)

¿Podría alguien explicarme qué sucedió en este caso, porque la ruta con el signo de interrogación hace que la imagen se vea así?

Comment: Bueno, posiblemente este [enlace sobre GET y envio de parametros](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/317.php) te ayude a comprender lo que sucede, obviamente no necesariamente debe ser PHP pero te dará una idea de que es lo que hace. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando cargas un recurso cualquiera (sea estático o no) y añades parámetros en el GET, lo haces después del signo de interrogación `?`

Cuando se trata de recursos estáticos (incluso, a veces se hace al cargar páginas), esta práctica suele buscar:

- garantizar que el recurso se cargue nuevamente desde el servidor y no se use el contenido en caché. Yo mismo tuve que hacerlo con páginas html porque IE decidía cargar caché incluso para páginas con formularios y datos dinámicos...
- enviar información al servidor que provee los recursos, permitiendo recoger info sobre cómo los usuarios están accediendo a la página.
- Dar info adicional para que quien sirve el recurso decida cómo procesar el mismo y entregarlo. En tu caso, por ejemplo, puede que la info (que parece serializada) diga en qué navegador, resolución o dispositivo estás para entregar la mejor versión de la imagen

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente esto "?" en una url hace referencia a peticiones de tipo GET lo que sigue después del "?" son los atributos, propiedades que se incluyen en la petición, la cual puede ser el tamaño entre otras características.